# Using an interactive shell over ssh seems to remove/prevent some control characters - bolded, underlined or reversed text is wrong

Tags: shell, ssh, terminal, ansi-escape

I've been trying to get my head around how terminal control codes/colors work, and as part of that I'm setting up bash scripts to have all my color schemes working correctly on all the machines I use, plus when ssh-ing into any of them. I noticed something funny about running `colortest-16` over ssh:

At my work machine, I run `colortest-16` and get this output:
[image: Correct terminal colors locally]

I'm using Windows Terminal as my terminal emulator, and I don't actually have a bold font turned on for it, but plain bold text (\e[0;1m) comes out black in any case, as per the left column.

However, if I ssh into my home machine and run `colortest-16` in the remote shell, I get this:
[image: Non-working colors over ssh]

Plain bold text (\e[0;1m) seem to be bright white: if you zoom into the left column of the image you can just barely see the bold text, and colorpicking on a screenshot confirms it is a different color from the background, which is off-white. Reverse doesn't work correctly. Underline doesn't work, although interestingly, if I run the color test again, underline does start working (but still not reverse or bold).

I have verified that $TERM is the same on both machines (`xterm-256color`). Note that I'm running both of these in a local tmux session (no tmux on the server when ssh-ing in), but I get the same results even without tmux.

If I run `colortest-16 | vim -` locally and over ssh, I can see that the exact same terminal codes are being output in both cases. If I run `ssh user@home-machine colortest-16`, I get *working* output from the remote machine. Does this seems to suggest that the remote shell is somehow messing up the escape sequences? What other reasons would there be for this output to be different? Would the output from `stty` be helpful here?

Further notes: `ssh -t user@home-machine colortest-16` does cause issues, so it seems like the pty allocation is somehow contributing to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `TERM` has no effect on the script (it is hard-coded).  What does have an effect is the actual terminal used to display the results.  Some terminals (such as [xterm](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:boldColors)) render bold colors as bright colors.  Some (such as Windows Terminal) reportedly do not.

(This [colortest-16](https://www.unix.com/man-page/debian/1/colortest-16/) manual page appears to refer to some reuse of a script named [16colors.sh](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/master/vttests/16colors.sh) from xterm's sources).

Comment: All of these examples are being run in the same terminal, Windows Terminal. You are right, it does not have proper bold support. My question is why does bold text show up *differently* with the 2 invocations, despite being in the same terminal. Further investigation actually suggests that conhost.exe is not translating the escape sequences properly as it acts as the pty for the windows port of openssh (even though conhost does support, for example, underlines, and bold text via bright colors).

Comment: Perhaps the ssh client on Windows is also a terminal emulator (and interpreting those control sequences).  If it is run in an older console window it would have to be a terminal emulator.

Comment: Turns out it was the pty in the Windows ssh server, as per [this bug](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/2661)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was [this bug](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/2661) in the pty in the Win32 OpenSSH server component.

Comment: conpty is separate from the openssh client (see [overview](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-introducing-the-windows-pseudo-console-conpty/))

Comment: For sure, I worded that poorly. The bug is in conhost.exe in Windows, but the windows port of openssh server is coded to use that as the pty. In fact, a useful fix for this bug is building OpenConsole.exe from [https://github.com/microsoft/terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal), renaming it conhost.exe, and replacing the existing one in c:\windows\system32.